# SWIFT - Can I store functions in dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, swiftui

I am trying to make some template pages of frequently used at work.
can I store function(button action) in dictionary?

'''

```
                        ForEach(buttonConfigure, id: \.self) { buttonConfigure in

                            Button(action: {
                                buttonConfigure["action"]!
                            }, label: {
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Text(buttonConfigure["text"]!)
                                        .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium))
                                    Spacer()
                                }
                            })
                                .frame(height: FrameSize.btnFullheight, alignment: .center)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.init(hex: buttonConfigure["foreColor"]!))
                                .background(Color.init(hex: buttonConfigure["backColor"]!))
                                .cornerRadius(6)
```

'''

and here is dictionary.
Keys such as "text", "foreColor", "backColor" work well,
but I don't know how can I make "action" key works.

'''

```
var buttonConfigureDict = [
    ["text": "Delete", "foreColor": "#707070", "backColor": "#E6E6E6",
     "action": "self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()"],
    ["text": "Clear", "foreColor": "#E6E6E6", "backColor": "#1E2A52",
     "action": "self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()"]]
```

'''

Comment: Create a struct to do this.

Comment: Yes, you can - `var buttonConfigureDict: [String: () -> Void]`

Comment: Please ask the actual question you want to ask. If your problem is defining a data type to store multiple different button types then ask about that. Not about storing functions in a dictionary. This is an XY issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can but you shouldn’t.

Create a struct to store this data.

```
struct DataModel {
  let title: String
  let foreground: Color
  let background: Color
  let action: () -> Void
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually there are over 10 keys and the number of combinations are too varied. I don't want to save all of button types that I need to use. That's the reason why I want to create a template to use when I want to create button. –

Comment: Whatever you do, make a type to define it. Avoid using a Dictionary like this. Especially when each value is a different type.

Comment: Also… ask the actual question you want to ask. You asked about putting functions in a dictionary. It seems like your actual question should be about storing data for multiple different buttons.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you and thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but why would you do that?
A better way is to save the button in a view which you can access the view later. Or maybe a global function or static function for future use.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually there are over 10 keys and the number of combinations are too varied. I don't want to save all of button types that I need to use. That's the reason why I want to create a template to use when I want to create button.